# Max number of Columns in Crystal reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

What is the maximum number of columns that can be displayed in crystal report? 
[Including all formats like landscape, A4....etc]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there is no theoretical limit to the number of columns you can have in a Crystal Report. You can alter the paper size, (depending upon the printer driver,) to something ridiculously large.

For example, the Cute PDF driver I have installed allows a page of 24 x 108 inches - over 2.7 meters. You can also shrink the column to virtually no width. I have done this when exporting data to a CSV file via a report, with no requirement for the report to be printed, with around 40 different columns of data in a line.